# Automatically apply login to every Stack Exchange site

Tags: support, login

I'm becoming more active, and I'd like to not have to log in to each site when I'd like to get started. Is there a way to log in in one place to have all accounts connected?

Yes, so I'm using Chrome, and when I click on the drop down in upper right then go to a site where I don't have an account yet, go to the site, I don't have the privileges of a logged-in user. For example, if I click on the drop down again, I don't have an inbox as I would if I did it now.

Comment: Well, the accounts are "connected," in a sense. When you "link accounts" you earn 100 rep. As for having that login work cross-site, it's not really a big deal to me...they *are* on different domains, after all.

Comment: I suppose you're right, I'll only have to do it once anyways.

Answer (score 3):

This should already work; SO rolled out ["Global Network Auto-Login"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/11/global-network-auto-login/) in September. You should get a banner like the following:

[image: Image stolen from Jeff's blog entry]

---

Are you having problems with it, or had you just not tried yet? If it's not working you might want to [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/72366/edit) in what's happening and what browser you're using

Comment: I believe he means he wants to short-circuit the account re-creation process.

Comment: @drachenstern What would that entail? SO already doesn't have much of a "registration", you login and it says "hey, we're going to link your accounts", and you say "ok"

Comment: I'm just guessing here, @tshauck would have to say for sure.

Comment: Still needs to create a new login for every stack exchange site.